# Thom-type isomorphism on sheaf cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a smooth, projective surface and $T$ a finite set of points in $X$ i.e., of codimension $2$ in $X$. Is it true that $H^i(\mathcal{O}_X)=H^i(\mathcal{O}_{X\backslash T})$ for $i \ge 1$?

Comment: No, this is false. Look at SGA 2, in particular chap. III.